# AngularFire retrieve large amount of data from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm new to AngularFire and Firebase.

I have thousands of records on my Firebase Databaes.

here is my sample code

```
    appMainModule.controller('GetCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$anchorScroll', '$location', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $anchorScroll, $location) {
             var ReportObject = new Firebase("https://URL/UsersData"); 
             console.log("in Reports");
             var query=ReportObject.orderByChild("recordDate").startAt(someStartDateInMiliseconds).endAt(someEndDateInMiliseconds)
             var Reportsync = $firebaseArray(query); 
             $scope.tablesData = Reportsync;

             $scope.tablesData.$loaded(function (data) {
                 $scope.setTableByPro();
             });
             var secondQuery=ReportObject.orderByChild("recordDate").startAt(newStartDateInMiliseconds).endAt(newEndDateInMiliseconds)

         }]);
```

In above sample code, at bewlow line, the node `UsersData` contains `1000K` records

```
var ReportObject = new Firebase("https://URL/UsersData");
```

and in above sample code, at below line, the query will return for example `200K` records

```
var query=ReportObject.orderByChild("recordDate").startAt(someStartDateInMiliseconds).endAt(someEndDateInMiliseconds)
```

and in above sample code,at below line,date range changes and query will return `500K` records

```
var secondQuery=ReportObject.orderByChild("recordDate").startAt(newStartDateInMiliseconds).endAt(newEndDateInMiliseconds)
```

My questions are:

- will first line of code download `1000K` records?
- will the query orderByChild will query `1000K` downloaded data or it will query to firebase for data?
- and in my 2nd query will the query will download again 500k records ?

I'm confused, how firebase work in downloading data based on queries?